# If I initially hide my site using noindex, how quickly can I unhide it when wanted?

Tags: search-engine, meta-tags, google-search, search-engine-bots

Like the question says.

If my new website starts low profile, with restrictive tags such as `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` or `nosnippet` or `nofollow`, until a certain time, how quickly can I reverse those and become findable for search purposes?

**Note that I'm not interested in SEO and don't care about optimisation or ranking.**

I'm purely interested in using the correct meta tags, or other user actions (e.g. requesting rechecking by bots?), so I achieve "not in search results before a given time", and "findable with an appropriate search after that time", and how much lag to expect so I can take that into account for timing.

**How should I approach indexing, to achieve that?**